# mySQL Shell connection troubleshoot

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm having a tough job trying to make my MySQL connection through the MySQL Shell.

First off, it gives you options, such as: '\h' for help, '\q' for quit, '\c' to connect, etc.

I typed \c, for connecting, then it shows something as :

\connect [-] :

I don't know what this means, then I don't know what to put in it.

Bottomline is: there's something wrong with my *root* connection. Hence, I'm trying to reset my *root* password. But the connection to MySQL went south...

Comment: @KenWhite Then you've never used the `mysql` command line tool. It uses backslash for its commands.

Comment: @Barmar: Yet another thing MySQL does that isn't standard or is bass-ackward, I guess. One more reason not to like it. :-)

Comment: Those are just shortcuts, you can also type `help`, `connect`, etc.

Comment: @KenWhite These aren't command-line options, those use normal `-` prefix. This is input you type to the `mysql>` prompt.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. Still seems wrong to me, whether it's at the MySQL prompt or command line. *Everyone else does it this way, so we'll choose this way instead* seems to be the "standard" with MySQL.

Comment: BTW, on my systems `\c` is the shortcut for `clear`, and `\r` is the shortcut for `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

It wants you to enter the database and server hostname to connect to. You can type:

```
mysql>connect yourDatabase localhost
```

This is the same as providing the host and database when running the command:

```
mysql -h localhost yourDatabase
```

But if your database server is down, none of this will work. If you need help troubleshooting the database, you should be asking in dba.stackexchange.com.